# Assemble raid6 array from spares only

Tags: software-raid, mdadm, raid6

This question is related to [Managing raid6 device with pacemaker](https://superuser.com/questions/1782437/managing-raid6-device-with-pacemaker), but nothing in the question linked is relevant to this question, except the fact that `Pacemaker` is involved.

For the purpose of this question, I will assume the array is not distributed, but still managed by `pacemaker`. I created a `raid6` array that consists of 4 devices. `Pacemaker` manages both the array and all devices part of it, all as resources. I added the proper constraints so that the array is not assembled until at least 2 of its devices are started and available.

Troubles comes when one of these devices fail. Starting with a fully clean array, if one of the device fails, or if any of its own dependencies does, `pacemaker` deactivates the corresponding device via its resource agent. However, the device itself cannot be shutoff, because the active `raid6` array uses it. To get around this issue, I configured `pacemaker` so that it first fails the device on its array, then removes it. Then, since the device is not used anymore, it can deactivate the resource and shutoff the device.
In one of my tests, I suspect `pacemaker` failed and remove too many devices (3 out of 4) and shutoff the array. Now, `mdadm` refuses to assemble the array back:

```
[root@ceph01 ~]# mdadm --assemble /dev/md/disk1 /dev/cluster/ceph0*-disk1       
mdadm: /dev/md/disk1 assembled from 1 drive and 3 spares - not enough to start the array.
[root@ceph01 ~]#
```

If I examine each device, I find that 3 of them are marked as spares, and one as active:

```
[root@ceph01 ~]# mdadm --assemble /dev/md/disk1 /dev/cluster/ceph0*-disk1       
mdadm: /dev/md/disk1 assembled from 1 drive and 3 spares - not enough to start the array.
[root@ceph01 ~]# mdadm --examine /dev/cluster/ceph01-disk1 
/dev/cluster/ceph01-disk1:
          Magic : a92b4efc
        Version : 1.2
    Feature Map : 0x1
     Array UUID : 2929c57b:b3a7c8b6:36cb160e:b691c7a4
           Name : ceph02:disk1
  Creation Time : Wed May 10 16:19:13 2023
     Raid Level : raid6
   Raid Devices : 4

 Avail Dev Size : 7812667392 sectors (3.64 TiB 4.00 TB)
     Array Size : 7812667392 KiB (7.28 TiB 8.00 TB)
    Data Offset : 264192 sectors
   Super Offset : 8 sectors
   Unused Space : before=264112 sectors, after=0 sectors
          State : clean
    Device UUID : a83c4b13:338d9a52:54863e4b:6cb96cd3

Internal Bitmap : 8 sectors from superblock
    Update Time : Thu Jun  1 13:19:35 2023
  Bad Block Log : 512 entries available at offset 24 sectors
       Checksum : 7d767571 - correct
         Events : 175

         Layout : left-symmetric
     Chunk Size : 512K

   Device Role : spare
   Array State : .... ('A' == active, '.' == missing, 'R' == replacing)
[root@ceph01 ~]# mdadm --examine /dev/cluster/ceph02-disk1 
/dev/cluster/ceph02-disk1:
          Magic : a92b4efc
        Version : 1.2
    Feature Map : 0x1
     Array UUID : 2929c57b:b3a7c8b6:36cb160e:b691c7a4
           Name : ceph02:disk1
  Creation Time : Wed May 10 16:19:13 2023
     Raid Level : raid6
   Raid Devices : 4

 Avail Dev Size : 7812667392 sectors (3.64 TiB 4.00 TB)
     Array Size : 7812667392 KiB (7.28 TiB 8.00 TB)
    Data Offset : 264192 sectors
   Super Offset : 8 sectors
   Unused Space : before=264112 sectors, after=0 sectors
          State : clean
    Device UUID : 6196eccc:bd4d6f31:b7f12e0a:45482818

Internal Bitmap : 8 sectors from superblock
    Update Time : Thu Jun  1 13:19:35 2023
  Bad Block Log : 512 entries available at offset 24 sectors
       Checksum : 199889f1 - correct
         Events : 175

         Layout : left-symmetric
     Chunk Size : 512K

   Device Role : spare
   Array State : .... ('A' == active, '.' == missing, 'R' == replacing)
[root@ceph01 ~]# mdadm --examine /dev/cluster/ceph03-disk1 
/dev/cluster/ceph03-disk1:
          Magic : a92b4efc
        Version : 1.2
    Feature Map : 0x1
     Array UUID : 2929c57b:b3a7c8b6:36cb160e:b691c7a4
           Name : ceph02:disk1
  Creation Time : Wed May 10 16:19:13 2023
     Raid Level : raid6
   Raid Devices : 4

 Avail Dev Size : 7812667392 sectors (3.64 TiB 4.00 TB)
     Array Size : 7812667392 KiB (7.28 TiB 8.00 TB)
    Data Offset : 264192 sectors
   Super Offset : 8 sectors
   Unused Space : before=264112 sectors, after=0 sectors
          State : clean
    Device UUID : f85b705c:f5b270bf:a937406f:528916df

Internal Bitmap : 8 sectors from superblock
    Update Time : Thu Jun  1 13:19:35 2023
  Bad Block Log : 512 entries available at offset 24 sectors
       Checksum : 631d3bc1 - correct
         Events : 175

         Layout : left-symmetric
     Chunk Size : 512K

   Device Role : spare
   Array State : .... ('A' == active, '.' == missing, 'R' == replacing)
[root@ceph01 ~]# mdadm --examine /dev/cluster/ceph04-disk1 
/dev/cluster/ceph04-disk1:
          Magic : a92b4efc
        Version : 1.2
    Feature Map : 0x1
     Array UUID : 2929c57b:b3a7c8b6:36cb160e:b691c7a4
           Name : ceph02:disk1
  Creation Time : Wed May 10 16:19:13 2023
     Raid Level : raid6
   Raid Devices : 4

 Avail Dev Size : 7812667392 sectors (3.64 TiB 4.00 TB)
     Array Size : 7812667392 KiB (7.28 TiB 8.00 TB)
    Data Offset : 264192 sectors
   Super Offset : 8 sectors
   Unused Space : before=264112 sectors, after=0 sectors
          State : clean
    Device UUID : 8e577afd:eaafa63b:fda2a699:5d55ed8b

Internal Bitmap : 8 sectors from superblock
    Update Time : Thu Jun  1 13:18:40 2023
  Bad Block Log : 512 entries available at offset 24 sectors
       Checksum : 579e6b6b - correct
         Events : 166

         Layout : left-symmetric
     Chunk Size : 512K

   Device Role : Active device 3
   Array State : ...A ('A' == active, '.' == missing, 'R' == replacing)
[root@ceph01 ~]#
```

Having only 1 active device is enough to start the `raid6` array, since it means 3 devices are missing and `raid6` can handle only 2 failures. I can also see that all 3 devices marked as spare are set to the same `Events` counter (175) which is strictly higher than the one active device (166). I also know that devices 1,2 and 3 had slots 0,1 and 2 in the array, respectively, when they were part of it. However, `mdadm --examine` does not show that.

Since I have 3 disks out of 4, that were each of a different slot of the same 4 devices `raid6` array, and that all these 3 devices are clean and have the same `Events` counter value, I think it should be possible to re-assemble my array using them; but I cannot find out how.

I tried using only the spare devices and the `--run` flag to re-assemble the array:

```
[root@ceph01 ~]# mdadm --assemble /dev/md/disk1 /dev/cluster/ceph0{1..3}-disk1 --run
mdadm: failed to RUN_ARRAY /dev/md/disk1: Invalid argument
mdadm: Not enough devices to start the array.
[root@ceph01 ~]#
```

I tried the same command as above, but with the `--force` flag added:

```
[root@ceph01 ~]# mdadm --assemble --force /dev/md/disk1 /dev/cluster/ceph0{1..3}-disk1 --run
mdadm: failed to RUN_ARRAY /dev/md/disk1: Invalid argument
mdadm: Not enough devices to start the array.
[root@ceph01 ~]#
```

I tried letting `mdadm` discovering the devices it can use, only pointing at the `uuid` of the array I want to assemble, and with the `--force` or `--run`, or both flags:

```
[root@ceph01 ~]# mdadm --assemble --scan --uuid=2929c57b:b3a7c8b6:36cb160e:b691c7a4 --run
mdadm: failed to RUN_ARRAY /dev/md/disk1: Input/output error
mdadm: Not enough devices to start the array.
mdadm: No arrays found in config file or automatically
[root@ceph01 ~]# mdadm --assemble --scan --uuid=2929c57b:b3a7c8b6:36cb160e:b691c7a4 --force
mdadm: /dev/md/disk1 assembled from 1 drive and 3 spares - not enough to start the array.
mdadm: No arrays found in config file or automatically
[root@ceph01 ~]# mdadm --assemble --scan --uuid=2929c57b:b3a7c8b6:36cb160e:b691c7a4 --force --run
mdadm: failed to RUN_ARRAY /dev/md/disk1: Input/output error
mdadm: Not enough devices to start the array.
mdadm: No arrays found in config file or automatically
[root@ceph01 ~]#
```

Nothing worked so far and I am out of idea or suggestions to find on the web. Is there any way to get my array back?